# Is spring-data Kay-SR6 release compatible with elastic 6.2?

Tags: jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an application which uses an ELK with ElasticSearch version 6.2 (jhipster-console), plus another Elastic instance for my applicative document repository (for now a 2.4.6 version, as I'm on spring-data-elasticsearch 2.1.11).

Will I be able to use only one Elastic runtime when migrating to spring-boot 2 (so spring-data Kay SR6 suite) for both needs?

Side question, is it recommended to have only one Elastic datasource for both needs (applicative + monitoring)?

Comment: I would not recommend it. It will be safer to separate cleanly the application infrastructure from the monitoring one.
Moreover ELK is very sensible for versions of the different components. Basically Kibana requires Elaticsearch and Logstash to be on the same versions, so it will be hard to get an elasticsearch version that would work for both use case.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but some challenged me on that topic (mainly for the cost of operating two datasources) and getting some more arguments is priceless in this case ^^.